# How to apply Mixamo animation to avatar downloaded from Unity store

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, mixamo

I am new to Unity, I downloaded this santa clause [avatar](https://www.meshtint.com/products/free-santa-claus) from the Unity asset store. I also downloaded an animation without skin from Mixamo and renamed it to dancingAvatar. I want to apply the animation to my avatar so it can move around but can't figure it out.

If I use the santa clause avatar's FBX file, and click on select, it tells me **No animation data available** See:

[image]

If I use the avatar's prefab, and then click on select, it does not have any options for Model, Rig, Animations, or Material. See:

[image]

Should I not be using the prefab? Or is this asset just not compatible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

It worked for me. What you need to make sure is

> 1-`Meshtint Free Santa Claus` &  `DancingAnimation` `Rig Animation
>   Type` type should be `Humanoid`
>
> 2- make an `AnimatiorController` and add `DancingAnimationClip` (as
>   default).

[image]

[image]

EDIT : You are seeing `no animation data available in this model` because `Santa Model` contains no built-in animation/s.
But if you select the dancing animation model and see `Animation` tab in the inspector, you can see the details of animation.

[image]

Comment: I followed your post and made the dancing animation controller, then under Animator section of Santa Clause character, I set the controller to dancing animation controller. Why do I still see "no animation data available for this model" if I click on the character's `select` -> `Animation`?

Comment: Because Santa model has no built-in animations and you are using animation of another model of same rig. I have edited answer, please have a look.